# Create content snippet with Jinja filter

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I want to create content snippets for my home page.  An example post looks something like

```
<p>Your favorite Harry Potter characters enter the Game of Thrones 
universe, and you'll never guess what happens!</p>

<readmore/>

<p>...they all die</p>
```

On the home page I only want the things before `<readmore/>` to show up.  I'm thinking the I can use Beautiful Soup in a Jinja filter to cut out the readmore and all the content after it.  It should clip at the first newline or paragraph end if no `<readmore/>` is present.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use Beautiful Soup.  Just check if `<readmore/>` or some other substring is present in the text, and split on it, or if it's not there split on newline.

```
from markupsafe import Markup

@app.template_filter()
def snippet(value):
    for sep in ('<readmore/>', '<br/>', '<br>', '</p>'):
        if sep in value:
            break
    else:
        sep = '\n'

    return Markup(value.split(sep, 1)[0])
```